# How to use two different dynamic cells with a Table view in Objective-C (iPhone)?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have a tab bar controller with only two buttons in it. Each one goes to a distinct table view, but both tableview inherits from my TableViewController.m class. I have one dynamic cell in each table view. They both have a different name (the first one is "Places List" and the second one is "Photos and places list"). I want to display different things in each tab (which point to a table view), but I don't know how. I think I need to recognize the name of my dynamic cell in my controller to achieve that, but I don't know how either. Please help! This is the method in TableViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)sender 
          cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Places List";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [sender dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [cities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [restOfPlaces objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Why do they need to inherit from the same controller? Inheritance is the strongest form of coupling. If they share the same dataSource then point them at the same dataSource using delegate or composition is much nicer than inheritance

Comment: Well, they don't NEED to, but I thought there was an efficient way to programatically determine which cell could be shown in a table view. Anyway, if asked another way: how can I change the content of my table view depending on which tab is selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can either

1. add an ivar to the `TableViewController` and set it to the tab index when it is instantiated
2. Ask the tabBarController

   ```
   [self.tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self];
   ```

Both of these are ugly solutions and I would probably think about restructuring.

Comment: So, if these solutions are uncommon, what is the standard way to know which tab button has been clicked? Could it be simply that each button points to a different controller?

Comment: There not `uncommon` they are `ugly`. Like I said in my original comment share what can be shared. If you end up with a class that uses if statements all over for the same condition it's a code smell that you should probably make two classes (they may or may not inherit from a common class)

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll do 2 classes.

Another thing: I want to make a segue from the table view cell of the first button (on the tab bar). When the user clicks on a cell (again from the first tab button), it would segue to another list (a dynamic list generated that is depending on the cell clicked). How should I proceed? Should I make another different controller? If so, how do I get the information of who is the "sender" (on which user did the user click to get there)?